# colourise grep output

Tags: grep, colors, xterm

I have defined `grep` as

```
alias grep="grep --colour -iTHn"
```

So, the output is:

```
<filename>  <lineno>  <line with matching word>
```

Now, with my dark terminal, the filename color is almost unreadable.
I can do

```
export GREP_COLORS='fn=00;32'
```

to change my filename, or

```
export GREP_COLOR='00;35'
```

to change my matched word, but I have failed to do them together.

So, the question is, is it possible to highlight all the field of my grep output with custom value/ colour? Say, 01;34 to filename, 01;32 to linenumber and 01;35 to keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specifiers in `GREP_COLORS` are colon-delimited, so you can do what you're asking with this line:

```
GREP_COLORS='fn=01;34:ln=01;32:mt=01;35' grep --colour -iTHn <pattern> <file>
```

The details are of course in [the manual here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables).